Web scraping dynamic tables with pagination
I need help to web scrap the dynamic table in this website: rootdata
This table has multiple pages. I need to pull the first 200 rows of the table with 'No token' as filter.
image example
I will appreciate some guidance.
I am using Selenium but I am still not proficient on it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

gecko_path = 'geckodriver.exe'
service = Service(gecko_path)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
driver.get('https://www.rootdata.com/Fundraising')

time.sleep(5)

title = driver.title
print(f"The title of the page is: {title}")

#close dialog
for dialog in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'v-dialog__content'):
    for button in dialog.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button'):
        button.click()
time.sleep(1)

#wait token group
token = None
while not token:
    for header in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'el-collapse-item__header'):
        print(header.text)
        if header.text.startswith('Token'):
            token = header
    if token:
        break
    print('No token found, retrying...')
    time.sleep(1)

#expand token group
cls = token.get_attribute('class')
print(cls)
if cls.find('is-active') < 0:
    token.click()
time.sleep(1)

#click last radio button (no token)
radios = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'el-radio')
radios[-1].click()

#print table rows
tbody = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'tbody')
for tr in tbody.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr'):
    print(tr.text)
    print('\n')


The page only shows 30 rows, in order to expand it you must log in, how could you bypass that?

i do not have account, so the code print 30 rows, not 200.
